# capistrano - no servers matched

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my app to the web server via capistrano. When I run

```
cap deploy:cold
```

I get

```
executing "cd /home/toe/apps/gallery2/releases/20120719172307 && rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
`deploy:migrate' is only run for servers matching {:roles=>:db, :only=>{:primary=>true}}, but no servers matched
```

I did googled but did not found any solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to define a server for the role "db" in config/deploy.rb

```
set :domain, 'horse.mine'
# ...
role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db, domain, :primary => true
```

where domain is just an alias.